# SQL Server find entries existing in all distinct periods (or sequences)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Y where I once off insert room_ID, the period and a sequence (in the hope of making the problem easier).

I want to find the room_IDs that exist in all different periods (or sequences if this is easier)

In the example below, room_ID **2** is the one. Thank you

```
DECLARE @y TABLE
(room_id    numeric(10,0)   null,
 date_from  datetime        null,
 date_to    datetime        null,
 seq        int             null)

INSERT @y
SELECT 2, '2023-05-01','2023-05-02',1

INSERT @y
SELECT 5, '2023-05-01','2023-05-02',1

INSERT @y
SELECT 8, '2023-05-01','2023-05-02',1

INSERT @y
SELECT 2, '2023-05-02','2023-05-03',2

INSERT @y
SELECT 8, '2023-05-02','2023-05-03',2

INSERT @y
SELECT 2, '2023-05-07','2023-05-09',3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of unique periods/`seq` values then you can simply do

```sql
SELECT y.room_id
FROM y
GROUP BY
  y.room_id
HAVING COUNT_BIG(*) = (SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) FROM Period);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Uv6Ghkp7)

You can also synthesize the total

```sql
SELECT y.room_id
FROM y
GROUP BY
  y.room_id
HAVING COUNT_BIG(*) = (SELECT COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT y2.seq) FROM y AS y2);
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I do not have. The periods are created on runtime by user intercation from within an application

Comment: BUT I could do this I guess:  SELECT y.room_id
FROM y
GROUP BY
  y.room_id
HAVING COUNT_BIG(*) = (SELECT COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT seq) FROM y);

Comment: not sure if it will answer your question though. dont you rather want to know which room is there for a *range of dates* ?

Comment: @PanosPlat Yes that would work also